# Apache Mod_Rewrite is erroneously changing case

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule in my root .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^((?:Paired|Mobile)?Coupon|Raffle)/(\d+)/Image/?$       /product_image.php?type=$1&id=$2    [L,NC]
```

and the following code in /product_image.php

```
var_dump([
        "REQUEST_URI"=>$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
        "QUERY_STRING"=>$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]
]);
```

When I request /Coupon/9/Image/ I get

```
array(2) { 
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(16) "/Coupon/9/Image/" 
    ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(16) "type=Coupon&id=9" 
}
```

When I request /Raffle/2/Image/ I get

```
array(2) { 
    ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(15) "/Raffle/2/Image/"  
    ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(16) "type=raffle&id=2" 
}
```

The raffle request query_string is always lowercase, While case changes in the coupon request are mirrored in the query_string. How do I ensure the request case is preserved in the query_string?

---

My debugging before asking here:

- Removing the [No Case] flag causes a 404 error for the raffle request (case independent); the coupon request only matches for 'Coupon' as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, I am not able to replicate that behaviour on my side.

Comment: Hate to ask, but are you 100% sure your request was for uppercase `Raffle`? If not, anything else in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I do have other rules in my .htaccess but have commented them for the purposes of debugging. Also I am running xampp 5.5.19 (Apache 2.4.4) on a Win 8.0 laptop

Comment: Did you try in incognito mode? It's possible that your browser is caching a previous response from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "((?:Paired|Mobile)?Coupon|Raffle)/" was matching a folder named "raffle".